# I am working in Ioniic, I added a background image in css, but when I build the android app, there is a white space in place of that background image

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am working in Ionic, I've added a background image in CSS, but when I build the android application there is a white space in place of that background image, how can I solve this error?

CSS code is:

```css
.abc{
   background-image: url('/img/s.png') !important; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: please provide the full code

Comment: Not very much information, but I guess it's in the first slash. This goes to the root, which might be correct in the browser, but not on android. For example, if the css file is in the css folder next to the img folder do something like `background-image: url('../img/s.png') !important;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image should be at a path similar to **www/img/background.png**.

Make sure that start of your image path has **"../"** this will point it to the correct image path in your resource folder once the app is built for a device.

To set background image you can try below css.

```
.scroll-content{
  background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

in some ionic version

```
.pane{
  background: url("../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If you are using **ionic2** then in `src/app/app.scss`

```
.scroll-content {
  background: url("../../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**or**

```
ion-content{
  background: url("../../img/background.png") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```